# Error installation extentions Reportico on Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I installed the extension reportico through composer and already web.php configuration file, but when I go into Reportico Admin Page error instead. The solution how ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFSrf.png)

scrip web.php

```html
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'K1pkkP_iwACp933A03LotJ3AfRsyIb-D',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'reportico' => [
            'class' => 'reportico\reportico\Module' ,
            'controllerMap' => [
                            'reportico' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ReporticoController',
                            'mode' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ModeController',
                            'ajax' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\AjaxController',
                        ]
            ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move reportico to components array:

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'reportico' => [
        'class' => 'reportico\reportico\Module' ,
        'controllerMap' => [
            'reportico' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ReporticoController',
            'mode' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\ModeController',
            'ajax' => 'reportico\reportico\controllers\AjaxController',
        ]
    ]
]
```